# Creating mappings in Doctrine2 for meta table structure for use in FormBuilder

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, formbuilder

I have two tables:

Branches:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

BranchMeta:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| branch_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| metaname   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| metavalue  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to have different meta fields, like "phone", "email", etc. that may be multiple as well.

Currently I have this code (setters/getters are omitted):

// Entity/Branch.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Branch
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity\BranchRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="branch")
 */
class Branch
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BranchMeta", mappedBy="branch")
     */
    private $metadata;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->metadata = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
?>
```

// Entity/BranchMeta.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * BranchMeta
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity\BranchMetaRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="branchmeta")
 */
class BranchMeta
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Branch", inversedBy="metadata")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="branch_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $branch;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="metaname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="metavalue", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $value;
?>
```

And then I need to build a form to add a Branch like this:

```
Branch Name:  [_________]
Branch Phone: [_________] [-]
Branch Phone: [_________] [+]
Branch Email: [_________] [-]
Branch Email: [_________] [+]

[Submit]
```

Where "Branch Phone" fields point to branchmeta table with meta name "phone" and correspondent values, and "Branch Email" fields point to branchmeta table with meta name "email". Both can be dynamically added/deleted.

How can I build this using Symfony2's FormBuilder? I created BranchType like this:

```
class BranchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'branch';
    }
}
```

And BranchMetaType:

```
class BranchMetaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('value');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity\BranchMeta',
        ));
    }    

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'branch_meta';
    }
}
```

But then I got stuck... How to properly use BranchMetaType to build the desired form in my case? Maybe I'm missing something in data mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is a much more better solution:

```
/**
 * Meta
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="metaname", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"phone" = "MetaPhone", "email" = "MetaEmail", "dummy" = "MetaDummy"})
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class Meta
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MetaPhone
{
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MetaEmail
{
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MetaDummy
{
}
```

Doing this, we will have the same table, the same entities (+ one superclass entity) and we will work like with normal entities with them. No hacky ways anymore. I wish I new of this feature 7 months ago...

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the information is scattered in the cookbook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html under additional note section *Doctrine: Cascading Relations and saving the "Inverse" side*.

This issue impress me so that I put some actual coding/research on it. :)
Here is what I found.

In the `Entity\Branch`, tell doctrine to cascade its persist operation on metadata property and modify `setMetadata()` to set the current branch for each metadata going to be persisted.

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BranchMeta", mappedBy="branch", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $metadata;

public function setMetadata(ArrayCollection $metadata) {
    foreach ($metadata as $m) {
        $m->setBranch($this);
    }

    $this->metadata = $metadata;
}
```

In the `Form\BranchType`, add metadata field with the appropriate option, and of course set the default `data_class` to `Entity\Branch` (your `BranchType` above doesn't have this). In this Form Type, the `'by_reference' => false` option is important to ensure that the `setMetadata()` function is called during persist (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference).

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('name');

    $builder->add('metadata', 'collection',
                    array(
                        'type' => new BranchMetaType(),
                        'allow_add' => true,
                        'by_reference' => false,
                    ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(
                    array(
                        'data_class' => 'Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity\Branch'
                    ));
}
```

And, finally try adding some dummy branchmeta in the controller

```
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Branch();

    $branchmeta1 = new BranchMeta();
    $branchmeta1->setMetaname('dummy meta name #1');
    $branchmeta1->setMetavalue('dummy meta value #1');
    $entity->getMetadata()->add($branchmeta1);

    $branchmeta2 = new BranchMeta();
    $branchmeta2->setMetaname('dummy meta name #2');
    $branchmeta2->setMetavalue('dummy meta value #2');
    $entity->getMetadata()->add($branchmeta2);

    $form   = $this->createForm(new BranchType(), $entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately this is not what I want. This will add a single field collection in the form builder ('metadata'), but I want multiple filed collections ('phones', 'emails', 'faxes', etc.) that are all physically stored in the metadata table but are marked by the metadata name field. Let's say:  

    id:1
    branch_id:1
    name:phone
    value:(123)1231231

    id:2
    branch_id:1
    name:phone
    value:(312)1231231

    id:3
    branch_id:1
    name:email
    value:vasya@example.com

    id:4
    branch_id:1
    name:fax
    value:(123)2525122
  
And so on...

Comment: You can't get what you want with the standard way to create collection? That's weird. I see that those 'phones', 'emails', 'faxes', etc, can be easily coded using choice field type (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) in your BranchMetaType.

Comment: Maybe there is a standard and easy way to get the behavior I need. The issue is that your answer just does not solve this problem. Please check my own solution that I posted after you.

Comment: I see. However, by looking at the screenshot, you still can achieve that with the standard way, not by hardcoding phone, email, fax, etc into the Branch Entity. Thank you for sharing your solution, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to a solution that I can't call elegant but at least it works.

Branch.php:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity;

//use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Branch
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\Bundle\ConsysBundle\Entity\BranchRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="branch")
 */
class Branch
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BranchMeta", mappedBy="branch", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $metadata;

    /**
     * Virtual OneToMany field
     */
    private $telephones;

    /**
     * Virtual OneToMany field
     */
    private $faxes;

    /**
     * Virtual OneToMany field
     */
    private $emails;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->metadata = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->telephones = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->faxes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->emails = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /* ...setters and getters are skipped... */

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     */
    public function onPostLoad()
    {
        foreach (array('telephone' => 'Telephones', 'fax' => 'Faxes', 'email' => 'Emails') as $metakey => $metaname) {
            $metadata = $this->getMetadata()->filter(
                function($entry) use ($metakey) {
                    return $entry->getName() == $metakey;
                }
            );
            $meta = call_user_func(array($this, 'set'.$metaname), $metadata);
        }
    }
}
```

controller code:

```
private function checkBranchAdded($branch)
{
    foreach (array('telephone' => 'Telephones', 'fax' => 'Faxes', 'email' => 'Emails') as $metakey => $metaname) {
        $metadata = call_user_func(array($branch, 'get'.$metaname));
        foreach ($metadata as $item) {
            if (!$item->getBranch()) {
                $item->setBranch($branch);
                $branch->getMetadata()->add($item);
            }
        }
    }
}

private function checkBranchDeleted($branch)
{
    $newMeta = array();
    foreach (array('telephone' => 'Telephones', 'fax' => 'Faxes', 'email' => 'Emails') as $metakey => $metaname) {
        $metadata = call_user_func(array($branch, 'get'.$metaname));
        $newMeta = array_merge($newMeta, array_keys($metadata->toArray()));
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    foreach($branch->getMetadata() as $key => $item) {
        if (!in_array($key, $newMeta)) {
            $em->remove($item);
            $branch->getMetadata()->remove($key);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($activeMenu, $activeSubmenu, $activeSubsubmenu, $id, Request $request)
{
    /* ... some code ... */
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeConsysBundle:Branch');
    $branch = $repository->find($id);

    if (!$branch) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No branch found for id '.$id);
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(new BranchType(), $branch);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        $this->checkBranchDeleted($branch);
        $this->checkBranchAdded($branch);
        /* ... some code ... */
    }
    /* ... some code ... */
}
```

Form builder code.
BranchType.php:

```
class BranchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('telephones', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new BranchMetaType('telephone'),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'options' => array(
            ),
        ));

        $builder->add('faxes', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new BranchMetaType('fax'),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'options' => array(
            ),
        ));

        $builder->add('emails', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new BranchMetaType('email'),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'options' => array(
            ),
        ));

        /* ... other fields ... */
    }

    /* ... other methods ... */
}
```

BranchMetaType.php:

```
class BranchMetaType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'hidden', array(
            'data' => $this->name,
        ));
        $builder->add('value', 'text', array(
        ));
    }

    /* ... other methods ... */
}
```